# Positioning list-group-item buttons

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create this list-group-item example below with two buttons (instead of just one) that should pull to right and also be of equal height to the list-group-item itself:

[image]

At the moment I do have the skeleton working, but as you can see they are not positioning correctly. 
Thanks.

```css
li.group-btn {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.form-control,
.btn {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
       </span>

        <span class="pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
       </span>
        <span class="left">Cras justo odio</span>
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use i.e `display: table;` / `display: table-cell;`

```css
li.group-btn {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.form-control,
.btn {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="input-group" style="display:table; width:100%;">

        <span style="display: table-cell; border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 0 8px; vertical-align: middle;">Cras justo odio</span>            
        
        <span style="display: table-cell; width: 40px;">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span>ᐅ</span> Go!</button>
       </span>

        <span style="display: table-cell; width: 40px;">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span>ᐅ</span>  Go!</button>
       </span>
        
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: updated answer, maybee it helps... do you tried around with line-height?

Comment: thank you, this just about right! but the buttons are still not positioned to the right, as my image example shows..

Comment: another update. chaged the order of the html elements, added some padding and vertical-align. hope that helps